# is mq v9 docker image available for windows

Tags: docker, mq

I am looking for mq v9 docker image for windows.But I am unable to find the link to run the image on docker.Instead I have seen the links where most of the tool expertise have explained about the mq image for linux.
If anyone is aware of this, please share the link, it will be helpful for me.

Thanks.:)

Comment: Are you talking about "IBM MQ"?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are talking about IBM MQ.

There is currently no support for an IBM MQ Windows image. The only platform that is supported as a containerized platform is Linux.

Source: [No mention of any other platform than Linux on the Configuring IBM MQ in Docker Knowledge Center page](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.con.doc/q114482_.htm)

Now in theory you *could* create one by hand using the [sample MQ Dockerfile and config files available on GitHub](https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-docker) as a basis. However if you encounter problems with this then you won't be able to get any help from IBM.

That said. If you are talking about running the IBM MQ Docker image on a windows machine (so the host machine docker is installed on is Windows) then you can still run the Linux image inside that docker. For windows docker installs a VM where it runs the images and this VM generally is Linux meeting the requirements set out on the [Docker support on Linux systems](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.con.doc/q114484_.htm) Knowledge Center page